# System Monitor schema is not installed

Tags: system-monitor

System Monitor doesn't open and when i run it by terminal this error message appears

```
Gtk-Message: 17:19:45.121: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 17:19:45.125: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(gnome-system-monitor:5286): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 17:19:45.161: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor' is not installed
Trace/breakpoint trap (imagem do núcleo gravada)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to several online sources this can be fixed by installing "gsettings-desktop-schemas":

```
sudo apt install gsettings-desktop-schemas
```

However, this error suggests there may be issues with your desktop environment therefore it's prudent to reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

This `org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor.gschema.xml` schema is contained in `gnome-system-monitor` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.gnome.gnome-system-monitor). You have to reinstall it by

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-system-monitor
```

If you find your GNOME fully broken, then reinstall it completely by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
```